# jQuery validation works, but still able to submit form if entries are incorrect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm using jquery validation plugin at my contact form, which returns if something is wrong in the form, but even if the entries are incorrect (for ex. name not longer than 1 character) I can submit the form and it sends the email with the incorrect data. How could I prevent the button from being active before the entries would be all correct?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newHTML = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="color:white; background-color:#6f8595; padding-bottom:15px; border-radius:5px;"><h3>Thank you for your message!<br />We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3></div>';

    $('#myform').validate();

    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var data = $("#myform").serialize();
        $('.form').html('').append(newHTML);
        $.post( "includes/sendmail.php", {data});
    });
});
```

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(function() {
  var newHTML = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="color:white; background-color:#6f8595; padding-bottom:15px; border-radius:5px;"><h3>Thank you for your message!<br />We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3></div>';
  $('#myform').validate();
  $('#myform').on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      $(this).html(newHTML);
      $.post( "includes/sendmail.php", {data});
    }
  }); 
});
```

Alternatively according to [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) you can execute the AJAX call in the validation submit handler - something like this:

```
 $('#myform').validate({    
   submitHandler: function(form) {
     var data = $(form).serialize();
     $(form).html(newHTML);
     $.post( "includes/sendmail.php", {data});
     return false;
   }
 });
```

Comment: Using this code reloads the site after submission and that's exactly the thing I want to avoid :)

Comment: e.preventDefault(); will stop the submission and NOT reload - if it reloads anyway, then there will be a message in the console with an error

Comment: Perfect, now it validates first, and if it's correct changes the html's content. Moreover it's clear and understandable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this code to solve the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var newHTML = '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="color:white; background-color:#6f8595; padding-bottom:15px; border-radius:5px;"><h3>Thank you for your message!<br />We will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3></div>';

  $('#myform').validate({
    onSuccess: function(form) {
      var data = $(form).serialize();
      $.post( "includes/sendmail.php", {data});
      $(form).html(newHTML);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This will submit the form AND try to ajax it too

Comment: Perfect, the code works just as expected and the result is exactly what I wanted. But where does that $form variable comes from into the onSuccess function? That part I don't get (yet).

Comment: delete "return true;" for prevent submit.

Comment: you can put the $form variable away when you call validate() function from the form selector.
this is for use validate function like this: $.validate(), for access to form object;

Comment: what if I'd just use `onSuccess: function() { ... ` without the $form?

Comment: I think that still working without any problem. you can test and tell me the result.